# Why variable still contains data after reference object gone

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

```
iframe1.map_data=iframe2.map_data
```

Is this not setting `iframe1.map_data` to a reference to `iframe2.map_data`?

When a new file is loaded into `iframe2`, why does `iframe1.map_data` still contain data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets not get iframes all confused in this.

```
var obj1 = {
  a: {test: 123};
}

var obj2 = {};
obj2.a = obj1.a;

// both properties point to the same object.
obj1.a; // {test:123}
obj2.a; // {test:123}

// modify a property of obj1.
obj1.a = 'abc';

// properties point to different objects.
obj1.a; // 'abc'
obj2.a; // {test:123}
```

This basically does what you are talking about, without iframes.

So properties *point* to objects, not other properties. `obj1.a = obj2.a` does not link the properties in any way. It simply sets both properties to point to the same object.

If I later point one of those properties to a different object, it doesn't change any other property.

---

However, if you modify the object that multiple properties point to, you can propogate meaningful change.

```
var obj1 = {
  a: {test: 123};
}

var obj2 = {};
obj2.a = obj1.a;

// modify a property of the shared object.
obj1.a.test = 456;

// both properties point to the same object.
obj1.a; // {test:456}
obj2.a; // {test:456}
```

Why dod that change both? Because in this case, `obj1.a` and `obj2.a` both reference the same object, and that object changed.

This time we modify the shared object. Where before, we modified objects that were not shared.

See the difference?

Comment: In your first example, if obj1 is deleted/changed, what is obj2.a pointing to?

Comment: Objects are only deleted when they have no more references pointing to them. So they continue to point to the object they were assigned, until they are told to point to something else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about this:

```
// Get references to 2 <iframe> nodes
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var iframe1 = iframes[0];
var iframe2 = iframes[1];

// Create a custom property
iframe2.map_data = { foo : 'bar' };
iframe1.map_data = iframe2.map_data;
iframe2.src = 'http://microsoft.com';

// This won't change, regardless of 
// loading a new document into iframe2
alert(iframe1.map_data.foo);
```

The `iframe2` DOM node will still be the same node even after you load a new document into that iframe. Since you created the `map_data` property on it, it will persist. Loading a new document into an iframe just modifies the frame's `contentWindow.document`, not the node that represents the frame on the main document.

Comment: Ok, but I tried iframe2.map_data=null and iframe1.map_data still had the data. Why is that?

Comment: If that's what you're asking, then Alex Wayne has your answer. Variables can't *be* references in js, they just *hold* references, which you cannot assign to.

Comment: So  iframe1.map_data holds a reference to  iframe2.map_data. After iframe1.map_data=null, what is  iframe1.map_data holding a reference to?

Comment: I will hold a reference to the object that used to be at `iframe2.map_data`, even after you nullified. you only nullified the other var, the object still exists. Again, please see Alex Wayne's answer, he gives a good example of that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `map_data` is. If it's an object, then yes, a reference is made. If it's something like an int, then no, it is cloned.

```
var t = {}, u = {};
t.hi = 3;
u.hi = t.hi;
t.hi = 4;
console.log(u.hi); // 3

t.hi = {x:3};
u.hi = t.hi;
console.log(u.hi) // {x : 3}
t.hi.x = 2;
console.log(u.hi) // {x : 2}

t.hi = 3;
console.log(u.hi) // {x : 2}
```